# MySQL, Mongo DB and Apache Solr

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, solr, document-oriented-db

We want to build a highly scalable website with high traffic and data (Imagine like youtube or facebook). We plan this to develop in PHP and MySQL.

We might need to store millions of data and also need to search faster. We heard that we have to use document-oriented databases and index servers for optimizing performance. We are looking at Mongo DB and Apache Solr as options.

Can someone explain how these technologies are different? We know that Apache Solr is used for optimizing search performance but does that mean searching data is slow in MongoDB.

We are a bit confused about the implementation of these technologies. Can someone explain us a solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193871/java-mongodb-solr-performances have a look to this...

Comment: We use MySQL and Solr as datastores. MySQL for stuff requiring transaction safety and Solr for individual user actions. MySQL is (caveat: I am no authority) just slightly slower than MongoDB when used as a denormalized, trivially atomic DB (which MongoDB is).

Answer (score 0):

It's not that MongoDB is slow in searching, it's that it's not a search index and does not support some advanced features like [full-text search](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Full+Text+Search+in+Mongo#FullTextSearchinMongo-TextSearch), ranking, etc.