# Can i Synchronize Apache Solr with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, architecture, solr, lucene, synchronization

I am using SOLR in my Application to implement Searching Techniques on Windows platform.

My database is MongoDB.

My question is whether it is possible to synchronize or integrate SOLR with MongoDb on the windows platform.

If i search in Google, results seemingly only specify using Ruby Script.

Our Previous Implementation with Postgres and Apache Solr is working successfully.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java - MongoDB + Solr performances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193871/java-mongodb-solr-performances)

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for a mongo data import handler, there are two projects on github:

Simplistic approach: https://github.com/james75/SolrMongoImporter

With support for delta imports: https://github.com/sucode/solrMongoDBImporter

I am writing a new one to cover for some missing features, and I'll publish it soon.

Comment: any progress with it?

Answer (score 1):

[This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542564/easy-way-to-sync-data-between-mongodb-and-apache-solr) lists a couple of possibilities. The interesting one, in my opinion, is using [10gen-labs's mongo-connector.](https://github.com/10gen-labs/mongo-connector)

From their description:

> The mongo-connector system is designed to hook up mongoDB to any target system. This allows all the documents in mongoDB to be stored in some other system, and both mongo and the target system will remain in sync while the connector is running. It has been tested with python 2.7 and python 3.

Furthermore, they have [a section describing integration with Solr.](https://github.com/10gen-labs/mongo-connector#usage-with-solr)

It seems to have been updated two months ago, so it's not a derelict project. I think the fact that it is a "10gen-labs" project is also a point in its favor, since 10gen is the old name of the company that makes MongoDB.